# Remove all completely blank rows

Tags: excel, vba, row

I have a couple thousand rows in a workbook.

There are several hundred rows that are blank.

How can I remove every **entirely** blank row?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways to do that:

**1. With VBA:**

There is a VBA script [here in this link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/deleting.htm). Use the first script, I mean **DeleteBlankRows**.

You can also copy the same code from [here](http://pastebin.com/i1HwekA1).

How to use:

```
Copy the code.
In Excel press Alt + F11 to enter the VBE.
Press Ctrl + R to show the Project Explorer.

Insert -> Module.
Paste code.
Save and Exit VBE.
```

Run the code:

```
Select the column with blank rows.
Press Alt + F8 to open the macro dialog box.
Select DeleteBlankRows
Click Run.
```

**2. Without VBA:**

Just check the [link](http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/01/26/delete-blank-rows-excel/) here. It is easy so no need to explain again here.

Comment: The "Without VBA" method (which is all over the internet) does not delete "completely blank" rows.  It instead deletes all rows that happen to have an empty cell somewhere in at least one of its columns.

Granted this post was from 2011, so maybe it worked in older versions of Excel??

Comment: I also don't like links for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'll paste the code here just in case the link dies in the future.

Just a note, the second part "Without VBA" will NOT meet the requirements of the original questions because it will delete rows that contain blank cells, but are not COMPLETELY blank.

Here's the code from the first link of the accepted answer.

```
    Sub DeleteBlankRows(Optional WorksheetName As Variant)
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' DeleteBlankRows
    ' This function will delete all blank rows on the worksheet
    ' named by WorksheetName. This will delete rows that are
    ' completely blank (every cell = vbNullString) or that have
    ' cells that contain only an apostrophe (special Text control
    ' character).
    ' The code will look at each cell that contains a formula,
    ' then look at the precedents of that formula, and will not
    ' delete rows that are a precedent to a formula. This will
    ' prevent deleting precedents of a formula where those
    ' precedents are in lower numbered rows than the formula
    ' (e.g., formula in A10 references A1:A5). If a formula
    ' references cell that are below (higher row number) the
    ' last used row (e.g, formula in A10 reference A20:A30 and
    ' last used row is A15), the refences in the formula will
    ' be changed due to the deletion of rows above the formula.
    '
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    Dim RefColl As Collection
    Dim RowNum As Long
    Dim Prec As Range
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim DeleteRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim FormulaCells As Range
    Dim Test As Long
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim PrecCell As Range

    If IsMissing(WorksheetName) = True Then
Set WS = ActiveSheet
    Else
On Error Resume Next
Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(WorksheetName)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Invalid worksheet name.
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Exit Sub
End If
    End If


    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(WS.UsedRange.Cells) = 0 Then
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Worksheet is blank. Get Out.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Exit Sub
    End If

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Find the last used cell on the
    ' worksheet.
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Set Rng = WS.Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=WS.Cells(WS.Rows.Count, WS.Columns.Count), lookat:=xlPart, _
searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

    LastRow = Rng.Row

    Set RefColl = New Collection

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' We go from bottom to top to keep
    ' the references intact, preventing
    ' #REF errors.
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    For RowNum = LastRow To 1 Step -1
Set FormulaCells = Nothing
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(WS.Rows(RowNum)) = 0 Then
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' There are no non-blank cells in
    ' row R. See if R is in the RefColl
    ' reference Collection. If not,
    ' add row R to the DeleteRange.
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    On Error Resume Next
    Test = RefColl(CStr(RowNum))
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' R is not in the RefColl
        ' collection. Add it to
        ' the DeleteRange variable.
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        If DeleteRange Is Nothing Then
            Set DeleteRange = WS.Rows(RowNum)
        Else
            Set DeleteRange = Application.Union(DeleteRange, WS.Rows(RowNum))
        End If
    Else
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' R is in the collection.
        ' Do nothing.
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Err.Clear
Else
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' CountA > 0. Find the cells
    ' containing formula, and for
    ' each cell with a formula, find
    ' its precedents. Add the row number
    ' of each precedent to the RefColl
    ' collection.
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If IsRowClear(RowNum:=RowNum) = True Then
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' Row contains nothing but blank
        ' cells or cells with only an
        ' apostrophe. Cells that contain
        ' only an apostrophe are counted
        ' by CountA, so we use IsRowClear
        ' to test for only apostrophes.
        ' Test if this row is in the
        ' RefColl collection. If it is
        ' not in the collection, add it
        ' to the DeleteRange.
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        On Error Resume Next
        Test = RefColl(CStr(RowNum))
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            ' Row exists in RefColl. That means
            ' a formula is referencing this row.
            ' Do not delete the row.
            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Else
            If DeleteRange Is Nothing Then
                Set DeleteRange = WS.Rows(RowNum)
            Else
                Set DeleteRange = Application.Union(DeleteRange, WS.Rows(RowNum))
            End If
        End If
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        Set FormulaCells = Nothing
        Set FormulaCells = WS.Rows(RowNum).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If FormulaCells Is Nothing Then
            '''''''''''''''''''''''''
            ' No formulas found. Do
            ' nothing.
            '''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Else
            '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            ' Formulas found. Loop through the formula
            ' cells, and for each cell, find its precedents
            ' and add the row number of each precedent cell
            ' to the RefColl collection.
            '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            On Error Resume Next
            For Each Rng In FormulaCells.Cells
                For Each Prec In Rng.Precedents.Cells
                    RefColl.Add Item:=Prec.Row, key:=CStr(Prec.Row)
                Next Prec
            Next Rng
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    End If

End If

'''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Go to the next row,
' moving upwards.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Next RowNum


    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' If we have rows to delete, delete them.
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    If Not DeleteRange Is Nothing Then
        DeleteRange.EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
    End If

    End Sub
    Function IsRowClear(RowNum As Long) As Boolean
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' IsRowClear
    ' This procedure returns True if all the cells
    ' in the row specified by RowNum as empty or
    ' contains only a "'" character. It returns False
    ' if the row contains only data or formulas.
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim ColNdx As Long
    Dim Rng As Range
    ColNdx = 1
    Set Rng = Cells(RowNum, ColNdx)
    Do Until ColNdx = Columns.Count
        If (Rng.HasFormula = True) Or (Rng.Value <> vbNullString) Then
            IsRowClear = False
            Exit Function
        End If
        Set Rng = Cells(RowNum, ColNdx).End(xlToRight)
        ColNdx = Rng.Column
    Loop

    IsRowClear = True

    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I found current answer unnecessarily long.

My code below is checking all used range rows one by one and if they are blank - it deletes them.

```
 Public Sub DeleteEmptyRows()
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Dim EntireRow As Range

    On Error Resume Next

    Set SourceRange = Sheet1.UsedRange

    If Not (SourceRange Is Nothing) Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        For i = SourceRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            Set EntireRow = SourceRange.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(EntireRow) = 0 Then
                EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```