# remove (partially) blank rows in excel

Tags: excel, formatting, dataset, organization

I have followed advice outlined here using either the VBA method or goto method, however my issue is a bit more complicated...

[Remove all completely blank rows in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232563/remove-all-completely-blank-rows-in-excel)

The difference is I have two tables. The table on the left has 300 rows filled with information in each cell. The table on the right has several blank rows, but corresponds to table one (it has 300 "spots" of information, many are blank).

I want to remove the entire columns with blank information in table 2. If there is a blank cell in table 2, I want to remove the ENTIRE row so the corresponding value in table 1 is also removed.

Please, if anyone has an idea how to do this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If table 2 is in column C for example.  This would find all of the blanks in that range and delete that entire row, which would include table1 if they are aligned as you suggested.

```
Sub DeleteEmptyRows()

Dim rngMyRange As Range
Set rngMyRange = Range("C1:C300")
rngMyRange.Select

On Error Resume Next
rngMyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However when I add the macro as a module I get a compile error: invalid outside procedure.